# Address of Local and global variables

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote this program to check the addresses of a local variable and a global variable. I read that stack segment stores local variables and data segment stores global variables. But when i executed this program ,the address of both variables does not have much difference, that implies they must be in same segment. Cant understand why this is happening.. here is the code and the output-

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int *chr;
    void main(){
        int *char1;
        printf("global- %p \n local- %p",chr,char1);
        chr=malloc(sizeof(int));
        char1=malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("malloc_global  = %p \n malloc_local = %p",chr,char1);
   }
```

the output is -

```
global- (nil) 
 local- (nil) 
malloc_global  = 0x969010 
 malloc_local = 0x969030
```

Comment: It is useful to understand that *any* type would do. You don't need to declare pointers. Declaring `char foo;` and printing `printf ("%p", &foo);` will print the location of `foo`.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Pointers printed with the `%p` conversion specifier should be cast to a type compatible with `void *`, if they are not already. Although rare in modern systems, different types of pointers may have different representations, and passing a type not compatible with `void *` to be printed with `%p` has behavior not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - you are right. My comment was originally meant as an addition to an earlier (now deleted) comment which suggested printing `printf ("%p", &chr)` as an answer to this question (as opposed to the OP's `printf ("%p", chr)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confused between the variables and where they are stored, and the contents of those variables; that confusion has arisen as you chose to use pointer variables, so there are two addresses that are relevant (where the pointer variable is stored, and what its contents are).

Let's have a look at what is happening.

`chr` is a global, and in the data segment. `chr1` is a local, and on the stack segment.

You are not however printing out where `chr` and `chr1` are stored, but the contents of `chr` and `chr1`. `chr` as a global is guaranteed to initialise to zero. `chr1` as a local is undefined. It is only by luck this is zero. You then allocate memory using `malloc` and assign the allocated addresses to `chr` and `chr1`. `malloc()` allocates on the heap and is used for both assignments, and so `chr` and `chr1` contain similar addresses. Again, you print the content of these variables, not where the address of them (i.e. where that content is stored). To do the latter you want:

```
printf ("global: %p \nlocal: %p\n", &chr, &char1);
```

Note the `&` operator which takes the address of the variables. The fact that the variables themselves hold content which is an address is (for this purpose) irrelevant; they could have been integers, for instance.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the OP's confusion. It is clear from the use of pointers and the OP's attempt to print their value that there is lack of clarity in the OP's understanding of pointers.

Answer (score 5):

> the address of both variables does not have much difference, that implies they must be in same segment

Correct. They are: both are pointing to heap addresses, which is where `malloc` allocates storage from. You can output the addresses *of the pointers* by using `&chr` and `&char1` as Mitch noted. Those might be more different (or not; your program is trivial, maybe the compiler still sticks them close together, even though they are in separate segments).

Comment: i checked &char1 and &chr and got this- global- 0x600990 
local- 0x7fffa55aec88 
malloc_global  = 0x600990 
malloc_local = 0x7fffa55aec88   this is a big difference in the address again. Please explain this

Comment: @imdad The address of the *pointer* doesn’t change when you change its content via `malloc` – why would it? The pointer itself is allocated on the stack (or global segment). Only the *pointee* address changes.

Comment: @imdad `&chr` is the address of the global variable. `&char1` is the address of the local variable. `chr` and `char1` are *contents* of the variables, which are the addresses that `malloc` allocated for you. Since `malloc` allocated both of those, they are in the same region of memory (the one `malloc` uses)

Answer (score 2):

Try printing out the values of `&chr` and `&char1`  rather than what their contents are pointing at.

`malloc()` allocates storage from the heap, and both variables are pointing to memory on the heap.